# Jquery Mobile select menu for Language or Countries

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, select

Can anyone tell me from experience what is the best method to create big lists of selecting items so the performance don't be harm.

I would like to make an settings page, where the user can select his country or language. Both select menues will be long over 20-30 items. I thought to make an overlayer with one radiobutton list and to give the user the control to scroll and select his item.

Is this performant? Is there one other cool solution?

I want to use this layout for Phonegap, what means ist there a way to use some native function to create this menus, it will be better to use them, insteat the JQM functions.

What do you mean?

Comment: only 20-30 items is not much, is it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand there is no cool magic way of doing this. jQM depends on jquery which is as fast as it can be.

20-30 items is not that bad. You should worry with 50+ items, 100 items select box takes about 2 sec to render.

Main performance problem is a listview("refresh") method. There is only one way to do it faster by using common js DOM methods. Unfortunately you will spend a lot of time replicating it correctly.

I will advice you to make a performance test on some older mobile device. If jQM is rendering listviews more then 500ms use some custom ajax loader to show that application is working. There's nothing else you can do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, if that is a *cool* solution, but instead of using a list to select from, 
you can use `navigator.appVersion` to determine the language automatically, see the following JavaScript snippet:

```
<script>
  alert(navigator.appVersion);
</script>
```

and the corresponding result on a Android device with Android 2.2:
[image]
you just have to parse for the language, in the example it is **de-de**.